# Error : Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys

I am creating a blog using Django. I want my author to be auto-selected in the author's box. Actually the box is getting correctly filled by javascript but when I submit the form it shows "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices." But I have provided it a TextInput Field. It works well when instead of TextInput, Select is provided to the author. But I don't want to let the author select I want it to get filled by the first_name who is logged in.

I want to update my choice list automatically when a new category is added on the form without shutting the whole server down and then run it again.

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post, Category
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# choices = [('coding','coding'),('entertainment','entertainment'),('sports','ssports')]
choices = Category.objects.all().values_list('name','name')
choice_list = []

for item in choices:
    choice_list.append(item)

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'title_tag','author','category', 'body', 'snippet')

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'title_tag': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'author': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 
                        'id':'gauname','value':'','type':'hidden'}),
            # 'author': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'category': forms.Select(choices=choice_list,attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'snippet': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

views.py

```
class AddCategoryView(CreateView):
    model = Category
    form_class =  AddCategory
    template_name = 'add_category.html'
    # fields = '__all__'
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    # body = models.TextField()
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='coding')
    snippet = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_posts')

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + '|' + str(self.author)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        # return reverse('article-detail', args=(str(self.id)))
        return reverse('home')
```

HTML

```
{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <h1>Add Post...</h1>
  <br><br><br>

  <form method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form.media}}
      {{form.as_p}}
      <!-- <input class = form-control type="text" id="gauname" name="author" value=""> -->
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" name="button">Post</button>
   </div>


  </form>

  <script>
    var name = "{{ request.user.first_name }}";
    document.getElementById("gauname").value = name;

  </script>
{% else %}

You are not allowed here!
{% endif %}


{% end block %}
```

UPDATE

forms.py

```
class AddCategory(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Category
            fields = ('name',)

            widgets = {
                'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            }

            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                self.fields["name"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                    queryset=Category.objects.all(),
                )
```

I want to update my choice list automatically when a new category is added on the form without shutting the whole server down and then run it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are two people with the same first name, how is Django supposed to know who is the user here? In other words, how can Django map the first name to a user? It doesn't make sense

Since it's a hidden field anyway, instead of `request.user.first_name` you can just pass `request.user.pk` instead (The Unique ID of that particular user)